# Let be $X$ a space with dense subset $D$. If $Y$ is a Hausdorff space and $f,g:X\to Y$ are continuous maps so that $f=g$ on $D$, then $f=g$ on $X$.

Tags: general-topology, limits, solution-verification, dense-subspaces

There are a few proofs out there that involve open sets, but I was wondering if my proof using limits was correct. Here it is:

*Proof.* Let $x\in X$. Since $D$ is dense in $X$, there is a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ in $D$ so that $x_n\to x$. Hence $f(x_n)=g(x_n)$. Since limits in a Hausdorff space are unique, and $f$ and $g$ are continuous, this implies that $$ f(x)=\lim_{x_n\to x} f(x_n)=\lim_{x_n\to x} g(x_n)=g(x). ~~~\square$$

Is this correct? I believe this works in $\mathbb{R}$, but my main concern was where to use Hausdorfness.

Comment: The existence of the sequence doesn’t hold in a general topological space. It only exists if the space is [first countable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space#Properties).

Comment: Ah, you're right. That's why it works in $\mathbb{R}$. So if $X$ was first countable, this would be correct?

Comment: Yes, or you can replace the sequence with a [net](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)) and everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

azif00 already mentioned in the comments that only $X$ being first-countable guarantees, that for any point $x\in X$, you find a sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ with $x_n\in D$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x_n\rightarrow x$ (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-countable_space#Properties)), so your proof only works with this additional condition. A relation of first-countable to other properties can be found [here](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/first-countable+space).

azif00 also already mentioned, that this can be bypassed by using nets, where we have, that for any point $x\in X$ there exists a net $(x_i)_{i\in I}$ with $x_i\in D$ for all $i\in I$ and $x_i\rightarrow x$ (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Characterizations_of_topological_properties) under **Closed sets and closure**). For a net like this, we have $f(x_i)\rightarrow f(x)$ and $g(x_i)\rightarrow g(x)$ since $f$ and $g$ are continuous (See also [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_(mathematics)#Characterizations_of_topological_properties) under **Continuity**). In a Hausdorff space like $Y$, the limit point of nets is unique (See Theorem 3 in "*General Topology*" by John Kelley [here](https://download.tuxfamily.org/openmathdep/analysis_real/General_Topology-Kelley.pdf) on page 67), so $f(x)=g(x)$.

I wouldn't use nets though, as there are a lot simpler and more elementary proofs as you said. For example is it a direct corollary (using $X=\overline{D}\subseteq X'\subseteq X$, so $X'=X$) of the following more general lemma:

**Lemma**: For $f,g\colon X\rightarrow Y$ continuous with $Y$ Hausdorff, the subset $X':=\{x\in X|f(x)=g(x)\}\subseteq X$ is closed.

*Proof*: $(f,g)\colon X\rightarrow Y\times Y$ is continuous. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, the diagonal $\Delta_Y\subset Y$ is closed and therefore $X'=(f,g)^{-1}(\Delta_Y)$ is as well.

Comment: +1 bes proof.  It also illustrates (unlike some other possibilities) why $Y$ is required to be Hausdorff.

Comment: OP starts with “There are a few proofs out there […], but I was wondering if my proof using limits is correct.”

Comment: @azif00 Thanks for bringing that to my attention! I totally forgot about that after immediately realizing this solution after reading the title. I will expand and edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't familiar with nets, here's how you can approach the general case: suppose for a contradiction there were $x\in X$ with $f(x)\neq g(x)$; since $Y$ is Hausdorff you can take disjoint open neighborhoods $V$ and $W$ of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$, and then $f^{-1}(V)$ and $g^{-1}(W)$ are both open neighborhoods of $x$, as then is $f^{-1}(V)\cap g^{-1}(W)$. Since $D$ is dense in $X$ you can find some $d\in f^{-1}(V)\cap g^{-1}(W)\cap D$, but then the element $y:=f(d)=g(d)$ is inside $V\cap W=\emptyset$ giving a contradiction.